# merging two files based on two columns in r

Tags: r

I have a `gff` file:

```
seqnames type ranges Name
Cch08   exon    57512691-57513280   ID=C08g068630.3.2:exon:2;Parent=C08g068630.3.2 ;
Cch08   mRNA    57512691-57514658   ID=C08g068630.3.2;Parent=C08g068630.3.2 ;Name=C08g068630.3.2;Note=Similar to C08g068630.3.2: ribosomal protein;ref_id=C08g068630.3.2;
Cch08   CDS     57512702-57513280   ID=C08g068630.3.2:cds;Parent=C08g068630.3.2 ;
```

Another file (`File`):

```
SNP                 Name        beta   t.stat   p.value       FDR
Cch08_57580286 C08g068630.3.2    7.92   77.7     1.51e-242 3.71e-237
Cch08_58328786 C08g068610.3.5   -12.9   -41.1    2.25e-145 1.96e-140
```

I tried merging both the files as I want to add `type` column from the `gff` file to the other file based on the column `Name`. I used:

```
merge(File,GFF,by="Name")
```

I got:

```
SNP                 Name        beta   t.stat   p.value       FDR       type
Cch08_57580286 C08g068630.3.2    7.92   77.7     1.51e-242 3.71e-237     mRNA
Cch08_58328786 C08g068610.3.2   -12.9   -41.1    2.25e-145 1.96e-140     mRNA
```

It is just showing `mRNA` for all the rows. I want it to give the `type` based on closest `ranges` column in `GFF`. I am not sure how can I add this criteria in the `merge` command. Thank you!

Comment: Please explain the rule set for your the type. In your case, the range of mRNA is closest to the the ranges given by SNP.

Comment: Yes, I want to find the closest genomic region the SNP belongs to, e.g., if it is in exon region or promoter or anything else.

Comment: For this type of domain-specific question, you are far more likely to get useful/appropriate answers from https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would convert `file` into a `GRanges` object and then use `distanceToNearest` to get the nearest element. Example loosely based on your data:

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(rtracklayer))
# generate gff file
write.table(
    data.frame(
        seqnames = "Cch08",
        source = "own",
        feature = c("exon", "mRNA", "CDS"),
        start = c(57512691, 57512691, 57512702),
        end = c(57513280, 57514658, 57513280),
        score = 0,
        strand = "*",
        phase = ".",
        attributes = c(
            "ID=C08g068630.3.2:exon:2;Parent=C08g068630.3.2 ;",
            paste0("ID=C08g068630.3.2;Parent=C08g068630.3.2 ;Name=C08g068630.3.2;",
                   "Note=Similar to C08g068630.3.2: ribosomal protein;ref_id=C08g068630.3.2;"),
            "ID=C08g068630.3.2:cds;Parent=C08g068630.3.2 ;"
        )
    ),
    "my.gff",
    sep = '\t',
    row.names = FALSE,
    quote = FALSE,
    col.names = FALSE
)
GFF <- import("my.gff", "GFF")

File <-
    read.table(
        text = "SNP                 Name        beta   t.stat   p.value       FDR
Cch08_57580286 C08g068630.3.2    7.92   77.7     1.51e-242 3.71e-237
Cch08_58328786 C08g068610.3.5   -12.9   -41.1    2.25e-145 1.96e-140",
        header = TRUE
    )

File <-
    cbind(setNames(data.frame(do.call(
        rbind, strsplit(File$SNP, "_")
    )), c("seqnames", "start")), File)
File <-
    GenomicRanges::makeGRangesFromDataFrame(File, keep.extra.columns = TRUE, end.field = "start")

dtn <- distanceToNearest(File, GFF)
File$type <- GFF[subjectHits(dtn)]$type

# optional: add ID of and distance to nearest element from GFF
File$nearest <- GFF[subjectHits(dtn)]$ID
File$dist <- values(dtn)$distance
File
#> GRanges object with 2 ranges and 9 metadata columns:
#>       seqnames    ranges strand |            SNP           Name      beta
#>          <Rle> <IRanges>  <Rle> |    <character>    <character> <numeric>
#>   [1]    Cch08  57580286      * | Cch08_57580286 C08g068630.3.2      7.92
#>   [2]    Cch08  58328786      * | Cch08_58328786 C08g068610.3.5    -12.90
#>          t.stat   p.value       FDR     type        nearest      dist
#>       <numeric> <numeric> <numeric> <factor>    <character> <integer>
#>   [1]      77.7 1.51e-242 3.71e-237     mRNA C08g068630.3.2     65627
#>   [2]     -41.1 2.25e-145 1.96e-140     mRNA C08g068630.3.2    814127
#>   -------
#>   seqinfo: 1 sequence from an unspecified genome; no seqlengths
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Hello @user12728748, thank you! As I have a large gff file so I used: suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(rtracklayer))
GFF = rtracklayer::import("gene_models.gff")
File <- read.delim("File.csv")
File <-
  cbind(setNames(data.frame(do.call(
    rbind, strsplit(File$SNP, "_")
  )), c("seqnames", "start")), File) and I got an error: Error in strsplit(File$SNP, "_") : non-character argument

Comment: You will have to figure out how your `File$SNP` vector looks like in order to extract the required seqnames and position. From the data you showed, my approach works, but I cannot guess how other elements that you do not show look like.

Comment: Thank you! File$SNP looks like what I had in the original post. I just realized that I am using another file of similar kind where first value for File$SNP looks like C1.1ch08_57580286. Can the additional 1.1 mess it up?

Comment: To identify overlaps or vicinity between 2 `GRanges` objects you need the position and the seqname. If the seqnames don't match it won't work, obviously. But apart from this, it looks to me like not all `File$SNP` are having the pattern <seqname>_<position>, hence the approach gives an error.

Comment: Thank you! I tried adding as character using File <-
  cbind(setNames(data.frame(do.call(
    rbind, strsplit(as.character(File$SNP), "_")
  )), c("seqnames", "start")), File) and it worked.

Comment: Hi @user1567654, that worked. Thank you! Is there a way to calculate the distance between SNP and Name columns e.g., how far is the SNP Cch08_57580286 is from gene C08g068630.3.2? thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to do, so I propose a solution for the problem I believe you want to solve.

First we separate the ranges in gff:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

gff_new <- gff %>%
  separate(ranges, c("min", "max"), convert=TRUE)
```

Now we join the two data.frames

```r
file %>%
  separate(SNP, c("seqnames", "value"), convert=TRUE) %>%
  left_join(gff_new, by=c("seqnames")) %>%
  group_by(seqnames, Name.x, type) %>%
  mutate(dist = min(abs(value - min), abs(value - max))) %>%
  group_by(seqnames, Name.x) %>%
  filter(dist==min(dist)) %>%
  mutate(SNP = paste0(seqnames, "_", value)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(SNP, Name=Name.x, beta, t.stat, p.value, FDR, type)
```

which yields

```r
# A tibble: 2 x 7
  SNP            Name             beta t.stat   p.value       FDR type 
  <chr>          <chr>           <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>
1 Cch08_57580286 C08g068630.3.2   7.92   77.7 1.51e-242 3.71e-237 mRNA 
2 Cch08_58328786 C08g068610.3.5 -12.9   -41.1 2.25e-145 1.96e-140 mRNA
```

### Data

```r
gff <- readr::read_table2("seqnames type ranges Name
Cch08   exon    57512691-57513280   ID=C08g068630.3.2:exon:2;Parent=C08g068630.3.2 ;
Cch08   mRNA    57512691-57514658   ID=C08g068630.3.2;Parent=C08g068630.3.2 ;Name=C08g068630.3.2;Note=Similar to C08g068630.3.2: ribosomal protein;ref_id=C08g068630.3.2;
Cch08   CDS     57512702-57513280   ID=C08g068630.3.2:cds;Parent=C08g068630.3.2 ;")

file <- readr::read_table2("SNP                 Name        beta   t.stat   p.value       FDR
Cch08_57580286 C08g068630.3.2    7.92   77.7     1.51e-242 3.71e-237
Cch08_58328786 C08g068610.3.5   -12.9   -41.1    2.25e-145 1.96e-140")
```

Comment: Hi, thank you! I loaded GFF in R using GFF = rtracklayer::import("gene_models.gff"). When I tried your suggestion, it says: Error in UseMethod("separate_") : 
  no applicable method for 'separate_' applied to an object of class "function"

Comment: My answer is based on the assumption that both, gff and file, are stored in data.frames named gff and file. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with neither rtracklayer nor gff (never heard of it) .